# template augment deduction/substitution failed

Tags: c++, templates, bind

With help of some people here I've got the following code compiled (by adding 'remove_reference' ):

```
template< typename Fn >  
bool templateFunctionOne( Fn&& fn )
{
  int v = 5;
  return fn( v );
}

template < typename Fn >
bool templateFunctionTwo( Fn&& fn )
{
  std::future< bool > tk( std::async( std::launch::async,
                          &templateFunctionOne< typename std::remove_reference<Fn >::type >,
                          std::forward<Fn>(fn ) ) );
  return tk.get();
}

bool printThis( int value )
{
  cout << value << endl;
  return true;
}

int main()
{
   auto func = std::bind( &printThis, std::placeholders::_1 );
   return templateFunctionTwo( func );  
}
```

This compiles fine. Now if I wrap the two template functions into a struct, and calling it from an object of its inheritance class it just won't work:

```
struct TestParent
{
   template< typename Fn > bool templateFunctionOne( Fn&& fn )
   {
     int val = 5;
     return fn( val );
   }

   template< typename Fn > bool templateFunctionTwo( Fn&& fn )
   {
      std::future< bool > 
              tk ( std::launch::async,
                   &TestParent::templateFunctionOne< typename std::remove_reference<Fn>::type >,  
                   this, 
                   std::forward<Fn>( fn ) ) )  
      return tk.get();
   }
 };

struct TestChild: public TestParent
{
   bool printThis( int );
   bool test();
};

bool TestChild::printThis( int value )
{
  return true;
}

bool Testchild::test()
{
   auto func = std::bind( &TestChild::printThis, std::placeholders::_1, this);  
   return templateFunctionTwo( func );
}

int main()
{
   TestChild myTest;
   myTest.test();
   return 0;
}
```

The errors:

```
no matching for call to '(std::_Bind< bool ( TestChild::\*(std::_Placeholder<1>, TestChild*))(int) >) (int&)'   
     return fn( val )  
             ~~~~~~^~~~~~~  


functional:547:2: note: candidate: template< class ... _Args, class
_Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...)  [with _Arg = {_Args ...}; _Result =
_Result; _Functor = bool (TestChild::\*)(int); _Bound_args = {std::_Placeholder<1>, TestChild*}]    operator()( _Args&&... __args)  
^~~~~~~~
```

Anyone could help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is in wrong place while binding:

```
   auto func = std::bind( &TestChild::printThis, this, std::placeholders::_1);  
                                                 ^^^^
```

must be as second argument.

Second issue, you are not calling `async` function, instead you try to call `future` ctor:

```
   std::future< bool > 
              tk ( std::launch::async,
                   &TestParent::templateFunctionOne< typename std::remove_reference<Fn>::type >,  
                   this, 
                   std::forward<Fn>( fn ) ) )
```

should be:

```
 std::future< bool > 
          tk = std::async( std::launch::async,
               &TestParent::templateFunctionOne< typename std::remove_reference<Fn>::type >,  
               this,
               std::forward<Fn>( fn ) ) ;
```

Comment: My bad! I think when I copied the code over I made some mistakes:-(  In the original code 'this' was in the right place but still it doesn't compile :-(

Comment: not sure about the second issue. I think it is correct (could be wrong though). Could you compile the code and see if you could get it to compile? Thanks so much!

Comment: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc0065e4db4eceaf   this is your code, compiles fine.